# Does Visual Studio or Resharper have an auto-completion overwrite feature similar to Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Sometimes I'll have classes/methods/variables with similar naming. For example, `GetABar()` and `GetAFooWithABar()` (assuming for the sake of example that these aren't horrible names to begin with).

I get into situations where I want to change one of the calls from the former to the latter, and when I start typing in the middle of the name, I'll get an auto-complete suggestion. If I select the suggestion, the following results: 
`GetAFooWithABarABar()`

In Eclipse, there's a handy feature called completion overwrite which you can set as a default, or select on the fly by holding down `Ctrl` when you select the suggested term. Does Visual Studio or Resharper have a similar feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ReSharper, you get a different result if you complete with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will insert the text, as you describe above. But if you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will replace the text to the right of the text caret, and should give you the result you're after.

Comment: By the way, Enter/Tab behavior might be adjusted here ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Completing Characters | "Tab/Enter" comboboxes at the top of the page